# programmatically mount azure blob as network drive

Tags: powershell, network-drive

I am trying to automate the creation of network share which is of Azure file share, in the remote machine. When the script is directly executed in the remote machine, the script executes and no issues faced.

It fails if I try to orchestrate the script from a different machine (build server).

```
If (!(Test-Path Z:))
{
  cmdkey /add:$nfsstorageblob.file.core.windows.net /user:Azure\$nfsstorageblob /pass:$BlobAccessKey
  net use Z: \\$nfsstorageblob.file.core.windows.net\sensushare /persistent:Yes
}
```

Above is the code which I'm using and works absolutely fine if its run on the remote machine directly. At times I get "System error 1223 has occurred. The operation was canceled by the user." error is thrown.